# Sobolev inequalities and weak derivatives

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $p\in[1,d)$, $$p^\ast:=\frac{dp}{d-p}$$ and $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be bounded and open. It's well known that $$W_0^{1,\:p}(\Lambda)\subseteq L^q(\Lambda)\;\;\;\text{for all }q\in[1,p^\ast]\;.\tag 1$$

> So, if $u\in W_0^{1,\:p}(\Lambda)$, we know that $u$ is not only an element of $L^p(\Lambda)$, but even of $L^{p^\ast}(\Lambda)$. But what can we say about the weak derivative $\nabla u$ of $u$? By definition, of $W_0^{1,\:p}(\Lambda)$, $\nabla u\in L^p(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$. Can we show more?

Maybe we can show that the weak partial derivatives $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}$ of $u\in W_0^{1,\:p}(\Lambda)$ are elements of $W_0^{1,\:p-1}(\Lambda)$ and hence reapply $(1)$. Is that the case?

Comment: On the interval $(0,1/2) $ the function $$ f (x)=\int_0^x \ln^{-2}(x)x^{-1}\, dx $$ is in $W^{1,1} $ but the gradient is no better than $L^1$. Similar examples exist in higher dimensions and for different exponents $p $.

Comment: @Jose27 And what if $u\in W_0^{1,\:p}$? Can we show that its partial derivatives are in $W_0^{1,\:p-1}$?

Comment: You can extend the function to $(-/2,1/2)$ and multiply by a cut off to make it lie in $W^{1,1}_0$.

Comment: @Jose27 What I meant was: Shouldn't we have $\partial u/\partial x_i\in W_0^{1,\:p-1}(\Lambda)$ for all $u\in W_0^{1,\:p}(\Lambda)$ by the very definition of these spaces? Then, $(1)$ would yield $\partial u/\partial x_i\in L^q(\Lambda)$ for all $q\in[1,p^\ast]$.

Comment: I showed you a counterexample to your claim. I think you're confusing the order of differentiability and the integrability: We do have $\partial u \in W^{0,p}=L^p $.

Comment: @Jose27 Yes, I've confused that in the notation. What I meant is that $\partial u/\partial x_i\in W^{k-1,\:p}(\Lambda)$ for all $u\in W^{k,\:p}(\Lambda)$ and hence we can apply $(1)$ for $\partial u/\partial x_i$, if $k\ge 2$. That's trivial, but I didn't thought about that at a first glance.